# Moving records from one table to another - a few records at a time

Tags: postgresql-14

I have been using this query (successfully) to move records from one table to another in a Postgres database.

```
WITH moved_rows AS 
( 
    DELETE FROM tableB
    RETURNING *
) 
INSERT INTO tableA 
SELECT * FROM moved_rows;
```

For relatively small row-counts this works fine, but as the number of rows in tableB grows larger I need to move rows at a rate of a few million each time. I tried this....

```
WITH moved_rows AS 
( 
    DELETE FROM tableB
    RETURNING *
) 
INSERT INTO tableA 
SELECT * FROM moved_rows LIMIT 100000;
```

This inserts 100000 records into tableA, but deletes ALL records from tableB.

How can I transfer a fixed number of records from one table to another? Obviously I need to ensure that only those rows successfully moved from A to B actually get deleted from A. I have no particular selection criteria for exactly which records get moved, I just want to limit the time and resources for each transaction.

UPDATE - I've tried both of these variants, and neither works....

```
WITH moved_rows AS 
( 
    DELETE FROM tableB LIMIT 100000
    RETURNING *
) 
INSERT INTO tableA 
SELECT * FROM moved_rows ;
```

Or

```
WITH moved_rows AS 
( 
    DELETE FROM tableB 
    RETURNING * LIMIT 100000
) 
INSERT INTO tableA 
SELECT * FROM moved_rows ;
```

Both return `syntax error at or near "LIMIT"`

Comment: Move LIMIT into CTE.

Comment: What if you flip it around: INSERT… RETURNING and then delete based on that?

Comment: @RonJob - can't get anything like that to work, can you elaborate?

Answer (score -2):

```
WITH moved_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM <original_table> a
    USING <other_table> b
    WHERE <condition>
    RETURNING a.* -- or specify columns
)
SELECT [DISTINCT] * FROM moved_rows;
```